# Is there a tool for finding out what packages provide a file?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configure, package-managers

For example, if ./configure or Make tells me I'm lacking libX11.so.6, and it's nowhere on my system, is there a tool or website into which I could type

> libX11.so.6

followed by a distribution/arch and get back

> libx11-6
>   libx11-6-debug [or whatever; asking README would probably return reams of entries]

http://sysinf0.klabs.be/ does something similar for some distributions and architectures, but it doesn't seem to have more recent distributions. Also, they don't have an entry for the filename so you need to Google "packagename site:sysinf0.klabs.be".

I'm most interested in Ubuntu, but it would be good to know about similar tools for other distributions as well.

Comment: Ubuntu has a Package Manager inbuilt. Synaptic. Did you try searching there?

Comment: Probably belongs on serverfault

Comment: For Debian I use http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages for Debian

Comment: If Synaptic has this functionality please post an answer indicating where.

I indeed considered serverfault, but I am a programmer, this is something I come across while programming, and it's not about "networking, servers, or maintaining other people's PC's".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debian does that via the website:

- search the [Packages](http://www.debian.org/distrib/packages) page under *Search contents of packages*
- the [answer in this example](http://packages.debian.org/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libX11.so.6&mode=filename&suite=unstable&arch=any)
- options selected where 'packages that contain files whose name contain the keyword' for the unstable distribution (as it is the largest) on 'any' architecture

Ubuntu probably does something similar but I don't know the website / launchpad that well.

You could also fetch the index file `ftp://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/dists/sid/Contents-i386.gz` but as it changes frequently the website option is probably more convenient.

Comment: I'll take this - Googling "search contents of packages" helped me also get http://packages.ubuntu.com/, 
http://packages.opensuse-community.org/, and
http://rpm.pbone.net/

Answer (score 2):

```
$ sudo apt-get install apt-file
$ sudo apt-file update
$ apt-file search libX11.so.6
```

`apt-file` will let you list and search the contents of packages whether or not they are installed on your system.

```
$ sudo apt-get install auto-apt
$ sudo auto-apt update
$ sudo auto-apt updatedb
$ sudo auto-apt update-local
$ auto-apt run ./configure
```

For even more automation, `auto-apt` will detect attempts to access non-existent files and automatically prompt you to install the packages providing those files.

Answer (score 0):

There is many other tools to do this 
check this great page for this : http://www.debianhelp.co.uk/findfile.htm
It is for debian or Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

If you have a file on your machine, and you want to know which package is responsible for it, then (on Debian & Ubuntu) it's...

```
$ dpkg -S FILENAME
```

Comment: True yet irrelevant -- OP wrote "and it's nowhere on my system".